# Is it possible to obtain the penalized likelihood from a fitted GLM model in H2O?

Tags: h2o, glm

There are accessors such as `h2o.logloss` and `h2o.residual_deviance` but I want the penalized likelihood which is the value optimized during training. Is there a way to access this value without re-computing it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get this from the scoring history table `h2o.scoreHistory(model)` which will give you something like:

```
Scoring History: 
            timestamp   duration iterations negative_log_likelihood objective
1 2019-03-19 11:58:57  0.000 sec          0               509.21546   1.34004
2 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.053 sec          1               489.50869   1.28818
3 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.073 sec          2               488.06524   1.28438
4 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.090 sec          3               487.83225   1.28377
5 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.106 sec          4               487.79622   1.28367
6 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.116 sec          5               487.78870   1.28365
7 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.126 sec          6               487.78701   1.28365
8 2019-03-19 11:58:58  0.136 sec          7               487.78659   1.28365
```

Which gives you the negative log likelihood and the penalized negative log likelihood - which is in the objective column.

so you would just need to grab the last iteration to get the value of interest, which you can do with:

```
score_table = h2o.scoreHistory(model)
score_table[length(score_table),'objective']
```

where `model` is your H2O-3 model object.